# Is there a way to specify in C++ that a pointer points to data that is always valid?

Tags: c++, constants

In a function parameter that is a pointer (foo(void *bar)), you can use const to specify that either the pointer (the parameter) itself is constant (foo(void * const bar)), and/or the data that the pointer points to is constant (foo(void const *bar)).

However in the foo(void const *bar) case, this is just a guarantee to the caller that foo will not attempt to modify the data pointed to by bar.  It does not give bar any guarantee to foo that the memory location pointed to by bar will always be valid.

In cases where you are working with constant data within an executable image, if you could provide that guarantee to foo and if foo needed to keep a reference that data for longer than the duration of the function call, foo could simply keep a copy of the pointer rather than having to make a copy of the data.

Is there a way to encode this guarantee in the C++ type system?

Thanks.

Comment: You could take a `T const*&`, which would atleast ensure, that whatever you're handed is `const` on the caller site aswell, but I don't think that helps much.

Comment: You can always use things like boost tag system, which encodes non-type information in the type system.

Comment: Did you mean to ask "is there a way to specify that a pointer points to data that *will always be* valid"? There is a difference between "is" and "will always be". If that was what you meant, then one of the standard library wrapper classes like `shared_ptr` might do what you want.

Comment: For whose benefit do you wish to encode this information? As a hint to the compiler? Or as a kind of documentation for the developer reading/using the code?

Comment: `void const *bar` does not guarantee that the function will not attempt to modify the data. It communicates intention; the function can violate that intention by casting away the const and modifying the data.

Comment: @Oktalist - that is correct, "will always be valid" is what I meant.  Thanks, I'll research shared_ptr more (I've looked at it briefly but not long enough to know what it does).

Comment: @jalf - This would be developer documentation.  If I saw a function on an object take a pointer to raw data, save the pointer and then try and use it later, I would suspect a bug as this object has no way of knowing if the pointer remains valid after the end of the function call.

Answer (score 3):

Q: Is there a way to specify in C++ that a pointer points to data that is always valid?

A: No.  You are always empowered with the ability to shoot yourself in the foot :)

Comment: i see only a silly response to the subject, and no acknowledgement of the details provided beyond the subject. sorry (-1).

Answer (score 3):

Not with a raw pointer but you could use a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr instead which would communicate that the function has ownership of the pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker it doesn't guarantee it, but if it isn't then the caller is severely misusing shared_ptr or unique_ptr. The only way it wouldn't stay valid is if the caller did some shenanigans like pulling the raw pointer out of the smart pointer and deleting it.

Comment: My point was that using `shared_ptr` doesn't guarantee that the pointer it holds is valid, any more than calling a function guarantees that the pointer you pass in is valid. Garbage In, Garbage Out.

Comment: Thank you, I'll research those pointer types some more (I'm just using C-style pointers so far)

Comment: @PeteBecker the question doesn't mention checking that the pointer is initially valid (which you can't do), only whether you can store the pointer without the caller deleting it (which smart pointers do short of very unusual behavior by the caller).

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - the question asks how to "guarantee to foo that the memory location pointed to by bar will always be valid". "Always" includes "initially".

Comment: @PeteBecker the only way a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr can hold an invalid pointer is misuse by the caller. The only way that a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr can hold an invalid pointer is if someone deliberately loads it with an invalid pointer; they both initialize by default to nullptr. That's about as close to a guarantee of anything as you ever get in C++. Someone can always do something stupid and mess things up. And anyway, as he mentioned in a comment to another question, he was looking for a way of avoiding a use-after-freed situation, which is what my answer addresses.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - most programming problems come from accidental errors, such as passing a bad pointer. I would never call such a thing a deliberate action. But my statement still stands: it's just as easy to pass a bad pointer to a `shared_ptr` instance as it is to pass a bad pointer to a function.

Comment: @PeteBecker it's clearly far less easy. The typical way to make a shared_ptr is to construct it directly with make_shared or use new directly in the call to the constructor. If you only do one of those, there is no way to get an invalid pointer into a shared_ptr.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - yes, there are lots of ways to ensure that you don't **create** bad pointers. But that wasn't the question. The question was how to write the function's interface to **guarantee* that whatever object was passed in would **always** be valid. Writing coding guidelines for users is not a **guarantee**.

Comment: @PeteBecker you can't protect against morons. Using shared_ptr will guarantee a valid pointer in any case that doesn't involve morons.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real way to guarantee it if you accept a pointer as input. You could however maintain a table of valid pointers and let your input be an index into that table; you can validate that by making sure the index falls within the table.

Short of that, the best you can do is catch the exception/signal that occurs when a bad pointer is used and try to recover from it.

Comment: Well, catch the exception/signal that **might** occur when a bad pointer is used.

Comment: Thanks, but I was specifically looking at avoiding a use-after-free scenario.

Comment: @Matt -- it probably would have been quite helpful if you had mentioned that up front, as it's quite different from what you've asked. There are debug tools to detect this situation (valgrind on Linux, visual leak detect detector on Windows), in order to validate the code. If you're looking for something which is not just a debug tool, you'll need to implement it yourself -- perhaps something where your caller does not allocate their own memory, but rather they _must_ allocate and free it using routines you provide.

Answer (score 1):

the approach i have taken is to create a class representation which introduces a semantic that specifies the backing data is `static`. then just ensure it cannot be trivially constructed, or its data reassigned.

so no, there is not a direct language feature, but introducing that semantic is easy enough.

Here's an illustration on how to prevent clients from accidentally promoting standard data to an immortal data container:

```
template <typename T>
class t_immortal_data_container {
public:
  // how clients create t_immortal_data_container<T>,
  // avoiding implicit promotions:
  static t_immortal_data_container Create(T& pImmortalData) {
    return t_immortal_data_container(pImmortalData);
  }

  ~t_immortal_data_container() {
  }
public:
  ...
private:
  // private: ensure t_immortal_data_container<T> only can use
  // this constructor:
  t_immortal_data_container(T& pData) : d_immortalData(pData) {
  }
private:
  T d_immortalData; /* << as pointer or reference */
private:
  // prohibited -- no definition
  t_immortal_data_container() /* = delete */ ;
};
```

then you update your program to accept this type as parameters, and handle the cases accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, seems like a pretty heavy solution that I expect works (although I'd need to look up the "= default;" and "= delete;" syntax before I fully understood it)

Comment: @Matt you're welcome. **heavy:** not so. it's a very lightweight way to introduce these semantics. typically, you will create them on the stack, and need them as parameters in a few select places to ensure semantics. **syntax:** the syntax is C++11. `= default` is used to permit use of the copy constructor. `= delete` is used to delete the default constructor. this just means that the client may use the copy constructor, while forbidding use of the default constructor. i will just change it so it uses no C++11…

Comment: Thanks Justin.  When I wrote my last comment I was under the misimpression that you wrote this class expecting for the data itself to be encapsulated in it, rather than just holding a pointer to static data, so it's lighter than I originally thought.

Comment: @Matt exactly - it simply refers to your static data by pointer or reference. in some scenarios, you might just use its pointer as the definitive storage location (the static is this container, and creates the single instance of the data as a parameter to the constructor of the static instance). passing that container around could simplify some things, and prevent some bugs. even then, it would not cost much because no copy of the data is required; just ensure `T` is a pointer or reference. i try to minimize static data, so i don't actually use this in many places, but it does help at times.